# Close all open cordova Dialogs

Tags: android, ios, cordova, dialog, cordova-plugins

I'm using the plugin [cordova-plugin-dialogs](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-dialogs.git) on a hybrid application and I need to close all open dialogs triggered by the navigator.notification.confirm method, programmatically.
I tried to click on a hidden element to do this (since on runtime if I click outside the dialog this works) but no success. 
Is there a way to do this using javascript or some cordova capabilities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a requirement for this myself a while back.
The official version of `cordova-plugin-dialogs` doesn't currently support this functionality so I [forked it](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-dialogs) and [implemented my own solution](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-dialogs/commit/e9301a547d685d49fb3d3d4ca2e81393289f97ae).

My fork is a bit out-of-date with respect to the official repo, but it still does the job for me. If you want to give it a try, install my fork:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-dialogs
```

Then you can dismiss all currently open dialogs with:

```
navigator.notification.dismissAll();
```

Or dismiss the most recently opened dialog with:

```
    navigator.notification.dismissPrevious();
```

I should probably put this together in a pull request to get it merged into the official version of the plugin.

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer and great job. If I implemented only that method would it work? And it works both for Android and iOS?

Comment: As you can see from [my commit](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-dialogs/commit/e9301a547d685d49fb3d3d4ca2e81393289f97ae) it is implemented for both Android & iOS. If you wanted to, you could probably patch those changes across into the most recent version of `cordova-plugin-dialogs`

Comment: I'm using cordova-plugins-dialog  2.0.2 and get this error `TypeError: navigator.notification.dismissAll is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

@A.W, If you got the error `TypeError: navigator.notification.dismissAll is not a function`, load the plugin from github with : `cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-dialogs.git`